# Vue: How to get rid of duplicate content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an array of names using v-for I get the names, as you can see I have two v-fors where the content is duplicated in this example my content is small and doesn't look so scary in real life it can be much bigger and all the problem is that the content is repeated, I tried to apply slots but could not cope

**Template**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in array" :key="index" class="names">
      <div class="show-names">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        v-for="(girlNames, index) in item.girlNames"
        :key="index"
        class="names"
      >
        <div class="show-names">
          <p>{{ girlNames.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      array: [
        { name: "Alex" },
        { name: "Jacob" },
        { name: "Robert" },
        {
          girlNames: [
            {
              name: "Anna",
            },
            {
              name: "Kiwi",
            },
            {
              name: "Ava",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Yes, this picture shows where the content is repeated

[image]

You can also see code [example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-monad-wsc5s)

Comment: I'm not sure, which content is duplicated? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The only issue that Im seeing here is an unwanted `<p>{{ item.name }}</p>` getting displayed when the object doesnot have a `name` node.

Comment: I see you updated the question. But this is not repeated content. This is just 2 different loops with different data, because you have a nested data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see here is bad data structure. In my opinion it should be an object with two fields, which seperate in your case boys and girls, and in this object should be actual data:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      names: {
          boys: [
              { name: "Alex" },
              { name: "Jacob" },
              { name: "Robert" },
            ],
          girls: [
              { name: "Anna" },
              { name: "Kiwi" },
              { name: "Ava" },
            ]
          }
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

They your code in `template` will be like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="names">
      <div v-for="(item, index) in name.boys" :key="index" class="show-names">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
      </div>
      <div v-for="(item, index) in name.girls" :key="index" class="show-names">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```